# Centos. Несколько версий PostgreSQL и PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, centos

1) На сервере стоит PgSQL 8.4Можно ли поставить из пакета 9.1? Как разруливать подключения к ним? Повесить на разные порты?2) Стоит PHP 5.3Можно ли поставить рядом 5.4 и насколько правильно это будет?

Answer (score 1):

все это можно поставить конечно на одном физическом сервере или виртуальной машине но только если ставить не из пакетов а собирать в рукопашную, но это геморой еще тот.

лучше не ставить столько всего на одном сервере. разнесите по разным серверам. поставьте из пакетов, так будет проще поддерживать систему.

Comment: Спасибо! Согласен.

Answer (score 0):

В debian, например, ставится в папку вида /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main.Т.е. два пакета разных версий поставятся в разные папки. В центосе похоже наверно. В конфиге поменяете port на другой и все.

Comment: Всё зависит от того как собранные пакеты. Если мейнтейнер озаботился возможностью одновременной установки двух версий (для мажёрных версий такое иногда делается, см. например python, но в целом это скорее исключение чем правило). Даже если пакеты не конфликтуют по файлам, они могут конфликтовать за какие-то другие ресурсы (сокеты, порты), поэтому пакетный менеджер старается предотвратить одновременную установку двух разных версий одного пакета (в случае если такая возможность отдельно не проработана мейнтейнером этих пакетов, то тогда это уже просто два разных пакета, а не две версии одного)